# UIwebView optimize in real time the size (mb) of all the images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I need to load some different html string that contain a lot of images. Is it possible to automatic retrieve a low resolution image to show to the user to prevents the UIwebview to load the whole size of the image (for example more than 1 mb for image).

Answer (score 0):

dou can subclass `NSURLCache` and override `cachedResponseForRequest:` method to hook all `UIWebView` requests. In this method you can implement your own images loading logic / redirect requests. For example you can use your own server or any third party service to get resized copies of images.
I've just found one - http://boxresizer.com/